# Interactive 3d graphic using Python or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, browser, 3d, jstree

I'm making a Django Webapp and I need to generate a 3d graphic like this, with some results.

[image: 3D image]

I'm handling two options, one where the graphic will be interactive (rotate, move, zoom) and other where the graphic will be static.

Should I use a  JavaScript to make the graphic interactive?. Is **Tree.js** suitable for this task? Is there any other alternative I can use?

In case I make it static I would like to use Python to generate the 3D and then make several views of it. Which library should I use in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So , in Javascript , to create something like you are looking for would be using Tree.js as this is the most new javascript engine for rendenring 3D objects.
But if you're looking for another engines, I would recommend BabylonJs.
Have a look on this [project](https://www.eternalcoding.com/?p=253) where it's created a 3D chart.

Comment: Thanks Lucas. I'll check it out. I have not experience with JS. What do you think is the most suitable for a beginner?

Comment: I found this 3D graph render which uses Tree.js (https://github.com/anvaka/ngraph.three/blob/master/README.md) , you can see some examples here : https://github.com/anvaka/ngraph/tree/master/examples/three.js. It's looks more simple to use

Comment: Hi @Eduardo , I just found a chart library called Chart.js, its the easier javascript chart library I ever used : check it here http://www.chartjs.org/